# LDBL_MIN returns 0, LDBL_MAX returns #QNAN in C

Tags: c, printf

i am writing a simple program in C which prints out the value, the number of bytes allocated in memory, the maximum value and the minimum vale of each type of data. Actually i'm having problems just with the long double part.
Simply, it doesn't print out the value i assign to my long double variable, the function sizeof appears to work correctly only if it is used alone in the printf function, the LDBL_MIN value appears to be 0 but i don't understand what kind of type specificator i need to use and the LDBL_MAX value prints out 1.#QNAN.

Here is my code:

```
charactersPrinted=printf("\t\t\t--- Long double ---\nValore: %1.6f",x);
printf("\nBytes allocated: %d\n",sizeof(long double));
printf("Minimum value: %g\nMaximum value: %lg\n",LDBL_MIN,LDBL_MAX);
printf("(Characters printed= %d)\n\n\n",charactersPrinted);
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. In particular, your code doesn't show how `x` and `charactersPrinted` are declared.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

`%1.6f` doesn't make much sense: A minimum field width of 1 is redundant because `%f` will always produce at least one character of output. A precision of 6 is redundant because that's what `%f` defaults to anyway. The whole thing could be written as `%f`.

`%f` takes a `double`, not a `long double` (should be `%Lf`).

`%d` takes an `int`, not a `size_t` (should be `%zu`).

`%g` takes a `double`, not a `long double` (should be `%Lg`).

`%lg` takes a `double`, not a `long double` (should be `%Lg`).

See e.g. the [Linux documentation for `printf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).